# Running a legacy file based application w/ an application using key based data?

Tags: ibm-midrange, distributed-computing, hadoop-streaming

I have two applications: one is running on AS400 and leverages physical and logical files; the other application is a newer version of the same software leveraging key based RDB.  The SW uses a number of master data, for example, course catalog.  Can I abstract the architecture to use a data services layer (Hadoop maybe?) to map/serve/process data to both applications but feed back into the legacy files?  For context, I am asking as I am trying to think of an approach that would enable us to roll out the new version on the modern platform as opposed to taking on more tech debt.  Thoughts?

Comment: Of course you can. But without more details, there isn't much to say about direction.

Comment: Am happy to provide additional detail but wasn't sure what to include.  Let me know what would help give greater context.  Thanks much for your response.

Comment: Even if you actually running an AS/400, the DB in the OS is an RDB.  The Add Physical File Constraint (ADDPFCST) command has been available for a long, long time.  An expand SQL interface capable of defining tables, views and constraints was added in v3r1 (circa 1994).  If you're using modern POWER hardware running IBM i OS, and DB2 for i you have a quite powerful RDBMS at your fingertips.

Comment: First obvious missing info is the OS version on your "AS400". The capabilities vary greatly from older to newer. You might have a much easier time with newer versions depending on skills you have. It might also be helpfull to know why you're thinking that Hadoop would be relevant to the needs of your application. Other info elements could be helpful depending on you develop a statement of whatever your actual technical and business problem is. It's pretty vague so far.